# Should I always implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface in model?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit, wpf-4.0

If I have a model which is pretty much a readonly collection and dispayed on a grid, where the user selects a row.

Do I need to have INotifyPropertyChanged always implemented on the model? Is there a performance benefit of implementing vs not?

I would like to know if performance is impacted by UI trying to use something like

var x = Model as INotifyPropertyChanged;

which it wouldn't have used otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the model in any data bindings, then yes, you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` even if it is completely immutable.  The reason has nothing to do with performance, but to avoid a memory leak.

A `Binding` will always try to register for change notifications, and if you do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or expose discrete change events of the form `[Property]Changed`, it will register through the `PropertyDescriptor` API.  The default, reflection-based `PropertyDescriptor` implementation uses a global subscription table, and if for some reason the `Binding` does not unsubscribe cleanly, your view model will be kept alive indefinitely.  This is in contrast to the weak event pattern used when bindings subscribe to `INotifyPropertyChanged` notifications.  Bindings at runtime generally clean up after themselves, but the Xaml designer is notorious for leaking under these circumstances, causing your designer process's memory consumption to rise steadily as you work.

Comment: If the binding subscribes to changes anyway in the absence of INPC, then why do the bindings not update? (I'm just curious)

Comment: When using property descriptors, you only get notified of changes when the value is also set through the same property descriptor.  You can see this in action by binding two text boxes to the same CLR property (with no change notifications).  Change the value in one, and the other will update, because all bindings go through the same descriptor.  This doesn't do you much good when you want to change properties directly, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just displaying in on a `DataGrid` and not expecting any **UI interaction** that'll change the value of the `Model` then you do not have to implement `INPC`.

**WPF** is tied to the `INPC` mechanism to update the `UI` from the backing `Model`. You don't need it if you load it once and won't change again. However, `INPC` c*an be pretty handy and you need to implement it if say a business logic that requires you to update something to a different row then you can basically subscribe the other model's `PropertyChangedEvent` to do something to the other row when a property changed is raised.*

There is no performance benefit of implementing it.